# Dynamicaly delete the table row both on database and on JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

This code below let me delete the row from the table in jsp page but not from my database,how can i do this? In other words i need to delete the row (to my database) whenever is checked a checkbox on my jsp page. i need a dynamicaly delete table row both on database and on jsp page.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>destcode</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DELETE BUTTON CSS.css">
    </head>
    <style> Stable, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

    }
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
         <%

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
   Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
   Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
   String search=request.getParameter("search");
  ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEST WHERE COUNTRY='"+search+"' OR CITY='"+search+"' ");     
  %>
   <table style="width:100%">
 <table id="Dest_table">
       <tr>
    <th> Dest. No. </th>
    <th>Check </th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th> 
    <th>Url of Destination</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> <%while(rs.next()){ %>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("ID_DEST") %> </td>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" value="checked"/></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("COUNTRY") %></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("CITY") %> </td> 
    <td> <a href=<%=rs.getString("URL") %> > <%=rs.getString("URL") %> </a>

  </td>
  </tr>
   <% } %>
</table>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">
 function deleteRow(Dest_table) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(Dest_table);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;

                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }


    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: use ajax to solve this problem...........

Comment: what is ajax??? can u explain it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ use this as reference

Comment: Any alternative way? (without ajax)

Comment: with out ajax your page will be reload

Comment: its ok doesnt matter

Comment: show me your delete row servlet code

Comment: above is the code!

Comment: man where your delete request goes i didn't see

Comment: do this in check box `<input type="checkbox"  onclick='window.location.assign("/yourdeletejsppage.jsp?id=4")'/>`  and it will delete your the use request to redirect to item show page... i hope you understand...

Comment: i dont have it in cause i dont know how to syntax it.... it will be like  if(chk.checked)  , string chk=request.getValues("chk")  , resultset rs2=myStatement.executeupdate("DELETE FROM DEST WHERE ID_DEST='"+chk+'" ") or something like this

Comment: make new jsp file in your dir with deleteItem.jsp write delete logic in it and  in checkbox onclick="window.location.assign('deleteItem.jsp?id='<%=rs.getString("ID_DEST") %>')"

Comment: yes but how i will linked them with this jsp?

Comment: your current jsp file?

Comment: instead of this`<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" value="checked"/>` use this ` <input type="checkbox" onclick='window.location.assign('deleteItem.jsp?id='<%=rs.getString("ID_DEST") %>")'/>` it will call your delete jsp page

Comment: ah ok ... can u tell me also the syntax of the jsp delete page? because i am not sure

Comment: `myStatement.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM your_table_name WHERE dest_id ="+req.getParameter('id'));` write this query in your jsp

Comment: it doesnt delete it... from database... i need to delete the rows on database when the user checked the checkbox and press the button in jsp

Comment: you want to delete record on checked change or button click? and please show your full code..

Comment: if u see the above code , in every row of the table is a checkbox that user can check and press the button to delete the row that is checked with the checkbox , this row i want to delete it on database too

Comment: man you need to first check which check box is checked and if it is checked on button click this will be delete

Comment: if you dont mind can you please upload code in git so i can check what is issue with your code

Comment: i am new at this dont how  git works , is any alternative way to contact with you?

Comment: https://github.com/JHK1821/Dynamicaly-delete-the-table-row-both-on-database-and-on-JSP.git i upload them

Comment: i will check your code and respond you as soon as possible

Comment: are you able to redirect jsp page to delete page?

Comment: i send you in fb Giannis Variozidis

Comment: okey man i will send my some program

Comment: i did not receive your message ...

Comment: check your git repo issue section i wrote solution code there